# Python - categorizing items in a list based on occurrence in a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dataset like this (simplified):

```
foods_dict = {}
foods_dict['fruit'] = ['apple', 'orange', 'plum']
foods_dict['veg'] = ['cabbage', 'potato', 'carrot']
```

And I have a list of items I want to categorize:

```
items = ['orange', 'potato', 'cabbage', 'plum', 'farmer', 'egg']
```

I want to be able to assign item from the `items` list into smaller lists based on their occurrence in the `foods_dict`. I think these sublists should actually be `sets` as I don't want any duplicates in there.

My first pass at the code was like this:

```
fruits = set()
veggies = set()
others = set()
for item in items:
    if item in foods_dict.get('fruit'):
        fruits.add(item)
    elif item in foods_dict.get('veg'):
        veggies.add(item)
    else:
        others.add(item)
```

But this seems really inefficient and needlessly verbose to me. My question is, how could this code be improved? I'm guessing list comprehension could be useful here, but I'm not sure with the number of lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an efficient solution you want to avoid explicit loops as much as possible:

```
items = set(items)
fruits = set(foods_dict['fruit']) & items
veggies = set(foods_dict['veg']) & items
others = items - fruits - veggies
```

This will almost surely be faster than using explicit loops. In particular doing `item in foods_dict['fruit']` is time consuming if the list of fruits is long.

---

A **very** simple benchmark between the solutions so far:

```
In [5]: %%timeit
   ...: items2 = set(items)
   ...: fruits = set(foods_dict['fruit']) & items2
   ...: veggies = set(foods_dict['veg']) & items2
   ...: others = items2 - fruits - veggies
   ...: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.75 us per loop

In [6]: %%timeit
   ...: fruits = set()
   ...: veggies = set()
   ...: others = set()
   ...: for item in items:
   ...:     if item in foods_dict.get('fruit'):
   ...:         fruits.add(item)
   ...:     elif item in foods_dict.get('veg'):
   ...:         veggies.add(item)
   ...:     else:
   ...:         others.add(item)
   ...: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.57 us per loop

In [7]: %%timeit
   ...: veggies = set(elem for elem in items if elem in foods_dict['veg'])
   ...: fruits = set(elem for elem in items if elem in foods_dict['fruit'])
   ...: others = set(items) - veggies - fruits
   ...: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.34 us per loop
```

Surely, before choosing you should do some tests with "real inputs". I have no idea on the number of elements you have in your problem, and timings may change a lot with bigger inputs. Anyway my experience tells me that, at least in CPython, explicit loops tend to be slower than using only built-in operations.

---

Edit2: An example with bigger inputs:

```
In [9]: foods_dict = {}
   ...: foods_dict['fruit'] = list(range(0, 10000, 2))
   ...: foods_dict['veg'] = list(range(1, 10000, 2))

In [10]: items = list(range(5, 10000, 13))  #some odd some even

In [11]: %%timeit
    ...: fruits = set()
    ...: veggies = set()
    ...: others = set()
    ...: for item in items:
    ...:     if item in foods_dict.get('fruit'):
    ...:         fruits.add(item)
    ...:     elif item in foods_dict.get('veg'):
    ...:         veggies.add(item)
    ...:     else:
    ...:         others.add(item)
    ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 68.8 ms per loop

In [12]: %%timeit
    ...: veggies = set(elem for elem in items if elem in foods_dict['veg'])
    ...: fruits = set(elem for elem in items if elem in foods_dict['fruit'])
    ...: others = set(items) - veggies - fruits
    ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 99.9 ms per loop

In [13]: %%timeit
    ...: items2 = set(items)
    ...: fruits = set(foods_dict['fruit']) & items2
    ...: veggies = set(foods_dict['veg']) & items2
    ...: others = items2 - fruits - veggies
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 445 us per loop
```

As you can see using only built-ins is about 20x faster then explicit loops.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I am unfamiliar with the & syntax with sets. will have to research that one.

Comment: @DarwinTech: It's a shorthand notation for `set.intersection()`. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects

Comment: @bukzor Yes and no. The `&` arguments **must** be `set`s, while `set.intersection` accepts any iterable.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Weird special cases are weird. Why wouldn't they make them identical?

Comment: @bukzor If you say they are identical it means that every time you have `a & b` you can replace it with `a.intersection(b)` *and viceversa*. This is *not* the case. Sure is a small difference, but if you don't know it you may write `a & [1,2,3]` somewhere thinking it works while you get an exception.

Answer (score 1):

This might do what you are looking for (for e.g. the veggies case):

```
veggies = set(elem for elem in items if elem in foods_dict['veg'])
```

More fully:

```
veggies = set(elem for elem in items if elem in foods_dict['veg'])
fruits = set(elem for elem in items if elem in foods_dict['fruit'])
others = set(items) - veggies - fruits
```

Comment: Great! Both Bakuriu and EMS answers look good. Any opinion as to which is more efficient/ faster. Bakuriu seems a little more legible.

Comment: Using the `&` syntax is a good idea from the other answer; I just didn't know if you were willing to work with `items` as a `set` from the very start. However, I do not believe there would be any significant difference in speed between these two methods (even considering the 'benchmark' in the other answer), until you are talking about preposterously large arrays. And in that case, you'd want a more optimized data structure anyway. But in general, since this is a set-like problem, use as much set-like notation as you can (and @Bakuriu's solution is more optimal for that).

Comment: Yeah, I am actually happy to use sets form the get go, as duplicates are totally irrelevant. I also have to give extra marks to @Bakuriu for his comprehensive answer. All great answers though - thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this (avoiding list comprehensions using just set operations):

```
fruits = set(items).intersection(set(foods_dict['fruit']))
veggies = set(items).intersection(set(foods_dict['veg']))
others = set(items).difference(veggies.union(fruits))
```

And you can probably just start out with sets to avoid the set() conversion if you can help it.

Hope that helps!

EDIT: seems like you are concerned with either efficiency OR verbosity (and being "pythonic"). If you are concerned about efficiency remember that between the bytecode compiler and the interpreter you have no idea what optimizations (if any) are being implemented. It's generally difficult to optimize things in such a high level. Possible, but you need some benchmarks first. If you are concerned with being pythonic, I would try to be more high level (can I say declarative here? Or are we not there yet :) ).

In other words, instead of looping over and telling python exactly how it should decide which item goes where, I would try to be readable, clear and succinct. I think (because I wrote the above) that this style tells the reader exactly what you want to do with the list of items.

Hope this helps, all of this is just my opinion and should be taken with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more general if you have more categories.  (So you don't have a separate variable for each category.)

```
from collections import defaultdict

foods_dict = {}
foods_dict['fruit'] = set(['apple', 'orange', 'plum'])
foods_dict['veg']   = set(['cabbage', 'potato', 'carrot'])

items = set(['orange', 'potato', 'cabbage', 'plum', 'farmer', 'egg'])

dict_items = set.union(*foods_dict.values())

assignments = defaultdict(set)

assignments['other'] = dict_items.copy()
for key in foods_dict.keys():
    assignments[key] = foods_dict[key] & items
    assignments['other'] -= foods_dict[key]
```